# OpenType/TrueType version of AMS Euler

Tags: fonts

I'm looking for OpenType/TrueType version of AMS Euler. Or a similar, but free, font. Any hints?

I've checked https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf - it is too premature to use.

Comment: As far as I know Khaled Hosny's is the only project of this kind.